# Injecting ServiceEntityRepository results in Segfault / nginx Bad gateway 502

Tags: php, symfony, segmentation-fault, doctrine, entitymanager

We're currently rewriting our codebase, making this change:

```
// From
public function __construct(EntityManager $em){} // then use $this->em->getRepository(Example::class)

// To:
public function __construct(ExampleRepository $exampleRepo){}
```

In order to facilitate that, we update the `EntityReposity` to a `ServiceEntityRepository`. That helps significantly with unittest and goes well *most* of the time.

In some rare cases however we get a `502 Bad Gateway` and if we run `php bin/console`
 we get a 'Segmentation fault', which (at least to our understanding) means that C just breaks.

During our research we've created the theory that the ServiceEntityRepository load the EntityManager, the EM the Repos, which in turn load the EM again, etc.

Our packages are currently up to date per everyones suggestions everywhere, I'm hoping someone here will come up with a solution, now or maybe in the future. So, does anyone have any idea?

---

<sub>This issue appears related: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/30091</sub>

Answer (score 1):

<sup>For now I have a "temporary" solution which I'll post here so that others might have at least a work-around if they're searching for a solution. If I find out myself, I'll also update this question.</sup>

The error appears to be as is explained in the topic. The solution is to go that step back. Remove the Repository injection from constructor and use the `$this->em->getRepository(Example::class)` *in the methods*.  The following will *not* work, as you're still loading the repo in the construct, resulting in the loop:

```
function __construct(EntityManager $em){
    // THIS WILL NOT WORK!
    $this->exampleRepo = $this->em->getRepository(Example::class);
}
```

---

The issue appears a timing problem. The EntityManager loads the repositories, and each repository loads the Entitymanager, which in turn loads the repositories, ...
This results in an endless loop, which results in the interpreter running out of resources and returning the C error.

---

*Note: Not all repositories have this problem, thusfar we haven't found any pattern yet.*